# android - programmatically read incoming/outgoing emails for Google Account (Gmail App installed/not installed)

Tags: android, gmail, android-contentprovider

I am trying to read incoming/outgoing emails from a Google primary account. But I am unable to do this. I followed following source code (it was for Gmail app installed)

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver(); 
Cursor unread = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://gmail-ls/conversations/xxxxxx@gmail.com"), null, "label:^u", null, null); 
unread.moveToFirst(); 
int subjectIdx = unread.getColumnIndex("subject");

do {
   String subject = unread.getString(subjectIdx); 
} while (unread.moveToNext());
```

taken from a question from stackoverflow (forgot the link, my bad) but it isn't working. Is there any way I can read incoming/outgoing email for the primary Google Account

Comment: did you figure out the solution